# Copy and Paste Contents of Unix File

Tags: unix, ssh, command

I am trying to figure out how to copy the contents of a file after accessing it from a server via SSH. The format for the file is a single line of text that looks like a generated password but I dont know how to copy the password without downloading it. I also want to be able to paste it when I try to login to the server with that password instead of typing it out. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/157381/in-ssh-how-do-i-mv-to-my-local-system this might be helpful.